# How to format a math expression inside a text field?

Tags: java, swing, calculator, number-formatting, jformattedtextfield

I'm creating a Calculator software. In the text field as I'm typing, the *whole expression appears as one string* (and I want to keep it this way). Here's a demo:

---

[image]

---

I want it to be formatted like this:

- **NUMBERS - ###.###.###,######** (Grouping them into 3 digit groups, displaying fractions ONLY when needed and only up to 6 digits.)
- **Operators and Parenthesis - ###×(###-###)/###** (Should not cause any formatting errors or problems. I don't care if there is or there isn't a space inbetween the numbers and operators/parenthesis.)

Here's the above example in the correct format:

### 1.000×(5-3)/2

I also want it to **automatically update the formatting as I'm typing**.

---

Sofar I tried using `JFormattedTextField` with `MaskFormatters` and `NumberFormat` but neither of them worked as (described above) I wanted to.

NumberFormat version.

```
public class Frame {
    private NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    private JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(numberFormat);
}
```

MaskFormatter version.

```
public class Frame {
    private MaskFormatter maskFormat;
    private JFormattedTextField textField;
    public Frame() {
        try {
            maskFormat = new MaskFormatter("###.###.###,######");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textField = new JFormattedTextField(maskFormat);
    }
}
```

---

I managed to format the result using `DecimalFormat` but I don't want only the result to be formatted.

Formatting the result.

```
DecimalFormat resultFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.######");
String result = resultFormat.format(Parser.evaluate(expression));
textField.setText(result);
```

When I calculate 5/3 the result is:

[image]

Just as I wanted.

---

**Sorry for such a detailed and long post, any help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: "Just as I wanted" " excellent give your self a high marks then

Comment: I would use JTextField and add a DocumentFilter to the field (or even extend PlainDocument). Get the text, detect numbers, format them and let is pass to the Document

Comment: @gpasch That's not the answer to my question, it formats the result the way I wanted it, but when I'm typing the expression it doesn't work. Why so negative?

Comment: @Marko Kitonjics I'm sure that simple job for Java + ScriptEngine

Comment: @mKorbel I didn't mention it but I'd also like a ScriptEngine-free solution.

Comment: @Marko Kitonjics :-) search here - Java + Swing + ScriptEngine

Comment: @MarkoKitonjics you could use a keylistener and on every keypress format the numbers, is that what you need or ..?

Comment: You have a complex problem which won't be solved particularly easily. I'd start with a `DocumentFilter`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DecimalFormat resultFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.######");
Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");

String s = "1000×(5-3)/2";
Matcher m = numberPattern.matcher(s);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    double value = Double.parseDouble(m.group());
    String formatted = resultFormat.format(value);
    m.appendReplacement(sb, formatted);
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
// -> 1,000×(5-3)/2
```